# git ignore specific java class in Android Studio

Tags: java, git, github

I'd like to ignore specific java class from git. So I' posted inside root `.gitignore` file the full path of my desired class to ignore, but this class is still tracked by git.

```
app/src/main/java/com/my_pack/MyActivity.class
```

After updating `.gitignore` I run `git -rm cached app/src/main/java/com/my_pack/*` to exclude all content of `/my_pack` then `git add .` + push back but `MyActivity`persist there.

Any advices are apreciated.

p.s. using *github*

Comment: Note that adding a file to .gitignore will not untrack an already tracked file. You should probably ignore all .class files with `*.class`.

Answer (score 0):

Before `git add .` run `git status` and follow instruction for completely remove files.
For me it work.